# BLE - Reading multiple Characteristic values for a Service

Tags: delphi, bluetooth-lowenergy, firemonkey

I'm developping an App in Delphi communicating with a Smart device using Bluetooth LE.
This device has about 11 services and sometime up to 19 characteristics for a single service.
I'm able to discover all services and characteristics.

But I'm stuck when reading multiple characteristic values in a loop.
There is a short delay between:

**BluetoothLE.ReadCharacteristic(ConnectedDevice, GattCharacteristic);**

and

**BluetoothLECharacteristicRead** event.

How can I make sure I have correctly received the previous value before requesting the next one ?
Is there an example somewhere for doing that safely with Delphi?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: The `BluetoothLECharacteristicRead` event gets passed `ACharacteristic: TBluetoothGattCharacteristic` which includes more than just the value.

Comment: I can indeed read sucessfully the value for the first characteristic when the event is fired. When I'm trying to read the next characteristic for the same service, I get an error because BLE is not ready to process the next query.

Answer (score 0):

When the `OnServicesDiscovered` event is triggered, you must store the index of this Service (index in the list of available services on the current device). After that, you should access the list of available Characteristics for the current Service (in OnServicesDiscovered event there is a list of characteristics: `AServiceList[CurrentServiceIndex].Characteristics`) and perform reading values using the `OnCharacteristicRead` event, which is triggered individually one by one Characteristic that you want to read the value. In the `OnCharacteristicRead` event, there is 
a `ACharacteristic` parameter, which contains the current Characteristic information.

Using Bluetooth Low Energy:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_Bluetooth_Low_Energy

Comment: Thanks
Sorry if I didn't explain correctly my problem
I don't have any problem to read an individual characteristic. My problem is reading one by one up to 70 characteristics in a loop.
I'm asking to read the next one before getting the OnCharacteristicRead event fired for the previous request.
So far, I solved my problem by using a sleep(50) between each request to let BLE process the Read request. But of course this is not elegant.

I also have the same problem when subscribing for about 10 characteristics. It also takes time to be processed.
I was expecting BLE to be faster than that